# System.getProperties returning null for some values

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, system-properties

I am having some issues with my tomcat servlet hosted by amazon aws on elasticbeanstalk.

In an attempt to secure sensitive data, I am saving it in the web.xml file so that it can be referenced from `System.getProperties()`.

Some of this data, when called through `System.getProperties()` in code, returns null - while other data also called through `System.getProperties()` returns correct values.

My web.xml file is as follows:

```
    <env-entry>
    <env-entry-name>RDS_PASSWORD</env-entry-name>
    <env-entry-type>java.lang.String</env-entry-type>
    <env-entry-value>blah</env-entry-value>
</env-entry>
<env-entry>
    <env-entry-name>RDS_HOSTNAME</env-entry-name>
    <env-entry-type>java.lang.String</env-entry-type>
    <env-entry-value>blah</env-entry-value>
</env-entry>
<env-entry>
    <env-entry-name>DUMBDATA</env-entry-name>
    <env-entry-type>java.lang.String</env-entry-type>
    <env-entry-value>blah</env-entry-value>
</env-entry>
```

My code is as follows:

```
        w.println(System.getProperty("DUMBDATA"));
    w.println(System.getProperty("RDS_HOSTNAME"));
```

Although I try to access the data from the same methods and they are set up in the same way, `RDS_HOSTNAME` returns its correct value, whereas `DUMBDATA` returns null.

I appreciate any insight into this issue,

Thanks.

Comment: You have use JNDI to access Environment entries, an Environment entrie is not a system propertie.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something like

```
Properties p = System.getProperties();
Enumeration keys = p.keys();
while (keys.hasMoreElements()) {
  String key = (String)keys.nextElement();
  String value = (String)p.get(key);
  w.println(key + ": " + value);
}
```

to find out which ones are supported.